# What words does this Turing-machine produce?

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

Please take a look at the following Turing-machine:

[image]

Whatever the words may look like, they definitely have to end on a **b**, right? Because once the machine read the word, it looks at the first box symbol, from where it goes left. Now, it needs to look at a $b$ to go any further.

Is this correct?

You may also look at this turing-machine:

[image]

I'm looking for certain words here (it's a riddle) and I'm given the information that both turing-machines end on the same symbol. In the second turing-machine, I'm looking for a word of length 4. But wouldn't the only possiblity be the word be c|a|b|c then?

Unfortunately, this doesn't fit to the first turing-machine.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that the notation x/y,D means "read x from the tape, replace it with y and then go to direction D"? (Where D is R or L)

Comment: The two arrows at the very first state seem to mean 'if the current symbol is $a$, then stay in this state AND switch to another state at the same time'. Or maybe 'stay in the current state OR switch to the second one _at your will_'. Could you clarify the notation?

Comment: Additionally, what happens to the machine in the first state, if the current symbol is not $a$? Where should it go? Or should it stop?

Answer (score 1):

For the first machine: No, the word would not end with a $b$, since even if we assume that when it reaches the $\square / \square, L$ command the machine is to the right of any of the actual letters on the tape, after that it would have to read and write a $c$, move left, replace a $c$ with a $b$, move left, read and write an $a$ and stop ... meaning that the end of the word would have to be $abc$ .... which fits what you're saying for the second machine.